# Loading a third-party javascript library

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I developed a web radio player using Vue Cli. Now I have to add a new functionality using an external library (it's aimed to handle audio advertising) and **this library must be served from the remote host**. I can't just download the library and import it locally.

**Setup**

In my Vue App I have several components and in one of them I have an audio tag handling the radio playback. I need to detect the click on the play button, load the ad, play it and then go to the radio regular playback.

**Approachs I tried**

1. Loading the external library in the index.html file. It works but I can't interact with the player being loaded in Vue. For example, if I try to listen to the  play event in the index.html file (`audio.addEventListener("play", onPlay);`, I just receive "audio not defined" in the web console.
2. Loading the external library in the mounted () section of my component:

```
const triton = document.createElement('script')
triton.setAttribute('src', '//sdk.listenlive.co/web/2.9/td-sdk.min.js')
document.head.appendChild(triton)
this.initPlayerSDK()
triton.onload = () => {
  let player = new TDSdk(this.tdPlayerConfig)
  console.log(player)
}
```

The problem with this approach is that after `npm run serve`I receive the message `'TDSdk' is not defined`   which makes complete sense. I'm loading the external JS file but webpack isn't interpreting its content because that it's done in runtime. I have to add the external in my vue.config.js, but this doesn't work neither:

**vue.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  publicPath: './',
  /*configureWebpack: {
    externals: {
      tdSdk: 'tdSdk'
    }
  },*/
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
    .rule('images')
    .test(/\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp)(\?.*)?$/)
    .use('url-loader')
    .loader('file-loader') // not url-loader but file-loader !
    .tap((options) => { // not .option() but .tap(options...)
      // modify the options...
      options.name = 'img/[name].[ext]'
      return options
    }),
    config.externals([
      {
        'tdSdk': 'TDSdk'
      },
    ])
  },
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        sassOptions: {
        includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/compass-mixins/lib')]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  externals: {
    tdSdk: 'TDSdk'
  }
}
```

**myComponent.vue**

```
import tdSdk from 'tdSdk'
```

Comment: Add the script to HTML if you want `import` to work.

Comment: The thing is that the code must be served from the original source, not from localhost.

Comment: There's no contradiction. Modify it. See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I'm not understanding how to do it. I imported the library with a regular <script> tag and it doesn't work. If there's a way to do it with the <% %> syntax, I'm not getting it.

Comment: My workaround so far (it's working) it's to wait for the DOM to be ready (Vue fully loaded) and then add the event listener to the <audio> element:

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener("play", onPlay);
      });

Comment: There's no need for <% syntax. index.html plain HTML, it can be edited. Yes, the workaround is how this can be done in this case. However, you don't need to add a script dynamically and map it to an export in this case at all.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to load the library in the public/index.html file and then wait for the DOM being loaded so I could add the event listener to the audio element already loaded:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var playControl = document.getElementById('playIcon');
playControl.addEventListener("click", onPlay);
}
```

Then, in the Vuex store I needed to access the variables defined in the javascript located in the index.html. To do that, I set the `window.adState` (the var I'm using) as a global var in my store file:

```
Vuex.Store.prototype.$adState = window.adState
```

Finally, in my actions/mutations I used this.$adState to check its content:

```
playPause ({ commit, dispatch }) {
console.log('AdState', this.$adState)
(...)
}
```

<sub>*Answer added on behalf of OP.*</sub>

Answer (score -1):

The import cannot be resolved at the time when the script is evaluated because `TDSdk` global is not available. A script that is dynamically added to `head` is loaded asynchronously so there will be race condition any way.

`<script>` needs to be added dynamically if there's dynamic behaviour involved or like a condition or a developer doesn't have control over page layout. For static script, Vue CLI project's public [index.html](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html) can be modified:

```
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="//sdk.listenlive.co/web/2.9/td-sdk.min.js"></script>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
```

Application bundle is evaluated after the script and the global is expected to be available there.

Externals are commonly used for packages that were swapped to ones that were externally loaded, usually from CDN. Since `tdSdk` is not a real package and has no prospects to be swapped for one, it doesn't serve a good purpose to map it to a global and import it. It can be just used as `TDSdk` global in the application.

Comment: I totally understand your point. The only thing is that TDSdk it's not accesible from the application, that's the error message I'm receiving. My workaround uis to wait for the DOM to be ready (Vue fully loaded) and then add the event listener to the <audio> element: document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener("play", onPlay); });

The thing with this approach it's I can't interact with the ad object since it's not accesible from my app.